# How to create JSON from associative array

Tags: bash, json, mongodb, associative-array

I am writing a bash script on CentOS 7.5 that will execute some MongoDB commands. One of these commands will set replication servers. According to project, number of servers can be different.

I have this associative array that is the hostname an IPs of servers (I used an associative array because other parts of code needed it). In this example I have three servers:

```
  declare -A rep_hostname
  rep_hostname=( [test1]='172.1.1.1' [test2]='172.1.1.2' [test3]='172.1.1.3'  )
```

When having three servers, I have to run this command:

```
  rs.initiate( { _id : "opino-rs", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "172.1.1.1:2701" }, 
  { _id: 1, host: "172.1.1.2:2701" }, { _id: 2, host: "172.1.1.3:2701" } ]})
```

If my array has two server, I have this:

```
  rs.initiate( { _id : "opino-rs", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "172.1.1.1:2701" }, 
  { _id: 1, host: "172.1.1.2:2701" } ]})
```

I need to generate this command then execute it. The problem is I can't generate it. I tried few codes they weren't even close to what I wanted.
How can I do this?

Comment: Your expected JSON documents are both broken. They lack a closing `]` and the keys are not quoted. Consider updating the question.

Comment: How do you do the conversion from your associative array's keys to the `_id` values?

Comment: @Kusalananda there is no conversion between them. but it must start from 0. if i have 5 servers ir will be 0,1,2,3,4. i updated my json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A rep_hostname
rep_hostname=( [test1]='172.1.1.1' [test2]='172.1.1.2' [test3]='172.1.1.3' )

json=$(
        jo _id=opino-rs members="$(
                jo -a "${rep_hostname[@]/%/:2701}" |
                jq -c 'to_entries | map({ "_id": .key, "host": .value })'
        )"
)

printf 'rs.initiate(%s)\n' "$json"
```

Testing:

```
$ bash script.sh
rs.initiate({"_id":"opino-rs","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"172.1.1.3:2701"},{"_id":1,"host":"172.1.1.2:2701"},{"_id":2,"host":"172.1.1.1:2701"}]})
```

This uses both `jo` and `jq`.  The `jo` utility is a tool for creating JSON in the shell. `jo` will make sure that the generated JSON is properly quoted and encoded. The `jq` utility is a tool for parsing and processing JSON in the shell.

I'm using `jo` to create a JSON list of host names from the list of IP addresses in your associative array. Before creating the JSON array, I add `:2701` to the end of each IP address by means of a parameter substitution.

```
$ jo -a "${rep_hostname[@]/%/:2701}"
["172.1.1.3:2701","172.1.1.2:2701","172.1.1.1:2701"]
```

This is read by `jq` which modifies it into the list of JSON objects that we want to assign to the `members` key in the final JSON:

```
$ jo -a "${rep_hostname[@]/%/:2701}" | jq -c 'to_entries | map({ "_id": .key, "host": .value })'
[{"_id":0,"host":"172.1.1.3:2701"},{"_id":1,"host":"172.1.1.2:2701"},{"_id":2,"host":"172.1.1.1:2701"}]
```

This is use as input to `jo` again to construct the final JSON document.

At the end of the script, the generated JSON document is simply inserted into the parentheses in the string `rs.initiate()` using a call to `printf`.

Since I don't use MongoDB, I can't say how to then execute the result of this in the best way.

See also:

- `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/
- `jo`: https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/

Comment: are `jo` and `jq` different packages? or installing `json` is enough? i was testing the code and i got `jo: command not found` and `jq: command not found`

Comment: @BlackCrystal See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ for `jq` and https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/ for `jo`