# How can I create a JSON object from an associative array in shell using jo?

Tags: bash, json, jq, associative-array

I know about [How to create JSON from associative array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625501/how-to-create-json-from-associative-array) but that's not my problem.

I have this associative array:

```
declare -A aliases
aliases[Index]=components/Index/Exports
aliases[Shared]=components/Shared/Exports
aliases[Icons]=components/Icons/Exports
```

Now I need to convert this associative array into this JSON:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "Index": ["components/Index/Exports"],
            "Shared": ["components/Shared/Exports"],
            "Icons": ["components/Icons/Exports"],
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use `jo` and `jq`. But I can't come up with the nesting.

I tried this code:

```
jo -p compilerOptions[baseUrl]=. compilerOptions[paths]="$(jo -p a ${Aliases[@]})"
```

But it does not even run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution to this:

```bash
declare -A aliases
aliases[Index]=components/Index/Exports
aliases[Shared]=components/Shared/Exports
aliases[Icons]=components/Icons/Exports

jq -n --argjson n "${#aliases[@]}" '
        { compileroption: {
                baseurl: ".",
                paths:
                (
                        reduce range($n) as $i ({};
                                .[$ARGS.positional[$i]] = [$ARGS.positional[$i+$n]]
                        )
                )
        } }' --args "${!aliases[@]}" "${aliases[@]}"
```

Does not use `jo` and instead pass the keys and values of the associative array `aliases` into `jq` as positional parameters with `--args` at the end of the command (`--args` must always be the last option, if it's used at all).  The `jq` utility receives the keys and values as a single array, `$ARGS.positional`.  This means the first half of the array contains the keys, and the second half of the array contains the corresponding values.

The body of the `jq` expression creates the output object and uses a `reduce` operation over a range of `$n` integers from zero up, where `$n` is the number of elements in the `aliases` array.  The `reduce` operation builds the `paths` object by adding the positional arguments, one by one, using `$i`:th argument as the key and the `$i`+`$n`:th argument as the element in the corresponding array value.

---

A slightly different approach using `jo` to create leaf objects of each key-value pair of the associative array:

```bash
declare -A aliases
aliases[Index]=components/Index/Exports
aliases[Shared]=components/Shared/Exports
aliases[Icons]=components/Icons/Exports

for key in "${!aliases[@]}"; do
        jo "$key[]=${aliases[$key]}"
done
```

This would output the three objects

```json
{"Icons":["components/Icons/Exports"]}
{"Index":["components/Index/Exports"]}
{"Shared":["components/Shared/Exports"]}
```

Since we're using `jo` like this, we impose some obvious restrictions on the keys of the array (may not contain `=`, `[]` etc.)

We could use `jq` in place of `jo` like so:

```bash
for key in "${!aliases[@]}"; do
        jq -n --arg key "$key" --arg value "${aliases[$key]}" '.[$key] = [$value]'
done
```

We may then read these and add them in the correct place in the object we're creating in `jq`:

```bash
declare -A aliases
aliases[Index]=components/Index/Exports
aliases[Shared]=components/Shared/Exports
aliases[Icons]=components/Icons/Exports

for key in "${!aliases[@]}"; do
        jo "$key[]=${aliases[$key]}"
done |
jq -n '{ compileroptions: {
        baseURL: ".",
        paths: (reduce inputs as $item ({}; . += $item)) } }'
```

The main difference here is that we don't pass stuff into `jq` as command line options, but rather as a stream of JSON objects.

Comment: This works. But man, that code is so difficult. Even after years of experience I still could not write that code, let alone maintain it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati It's my first stab at an answer for your issue. There may definitely be simpler solutions, but I would need to come back to it later to see the problem afresh. In the meanwhile, someone else may provide an improved answer.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use `perl` or other proper programming language instead of a shell (especially bash!). Or at least switch to `zsh` with a better associative array support and use `perl` to do the JSONy stuff:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use JSON;

%my_aliases = (qw(
  Index   components/Index/Exports
  Shared  components/Shared/Exports
  Icons   components/Icons/Exports
));

$j->{compilerOptions}->{baseUrl} = "";
$j->{compilerOptions}->{paths}->{$_} = [$my_aliases{$_}] for keys%my_aliases;
print to_json($j, {"pretty" => 1});
```

Or:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

typeset -A my_aliases=(
  Index   components/Index/Exports
  Shared  components/Shared/Exports
  Icons   components/Icons/Exports
)

print -rNC1 -- "${(kv@)my_aliases}" |
  perl -MJSON -0e '
    chomp (@records = <>);
    %my_aliases = @records;
    $j->{compilerOptions}->{baseUrl} = "";
    $j->{compilerOptions}->{paths}->{$_} = [$my_aliases{$_}] for keys%my_aliases;
    print to_json($j, {"pretty" => 1})'
```

Comment: I think Perl support might not be widespread in docker images. That's why I chose to do it with shell.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, I'd expect `perl` or `python` to be more common than `jo` or `jq` though.